# Windows Azure and GitHub: build error on web.config

Tags: asp.net, azure, github, web-config

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project using the HotTowel SPA template. I haven't changed very much as you can see in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/petermorlion/Hourly/commits/master). I've set up Windows Azure to take in the changes and deploy to hourlee.azurewebsites.net, but nothing happened.

When I check my dashboard, it seems something went wrong. Windows Azure is complaining about an error in my Web.Release.config file.

More specifically, this is the error message:

```
D:\home\site\repository\Hourly\Web.Release.config(1,1): error : Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. [D:\home\site\repository\Hourly\Hourly.csproj]
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Hourly\Hourly.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="C:\DWASFiles\Sites\hourlee\Temp\208c4975-46bc-4f4f-89d8-6ae54a5289d8";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="D:\home\site\repository\.\\"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

It's repeated again (the entire message is longer).

I haven't changed anything in the web.config files and the whole thing builds and runs locally too.

I've noticed that it works when I remove the transform file (web.Debug.config and web.Release.config).

Comment: If anyone finds out how to fix it with the transforms, let me know and I'll accept the answer. In the meantime, I decided to make my application with NodeJS (it's an app for me to learn something new anyway).